# python plot animation in VS Code

Tags: python, animation, plot

i am using VS code to un this code :

```
import socket
from turtle import delay
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

HOST ='localhost'                                       # Server IP
PORT = 1234   
PORT1= 5678                                         # Server Port
BUF_SIZE = 1024                                         # Buffer Size
message = "Temp"
message1= "wind"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    # intialize a socket
s.connect((HOST,PORT)) 
s.sendall(message.encode())
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    # intialize a socket
s1.connect((HOST,PORT1)) 
s1.sendall(message1.encode())                                  # connect to server                                  # connect to server 

def animate():
    #s.sendall(message.encode())                             # send message
    data = s.recv(BUF_SIZE).decode()                        # wait to receive a message

    print('received temp: '+ str(data)) 
    if (int(data) > 30):
        LED="1023"
    else :
        LED="0"
    s.sendall(LED.encode()) 
    time.sleep(2)
    DT.pop(0)
    DT.append(data)                                          # close connection

    
    #s1.sendall(message1.encode())                             # send message
    data1 = s1.recv(BUF_SIZE).decode()                        # wait to receive a message

    print('received water level: '+ str(data1)) 
    if (int(data1) > 5):
        LED="1023"
    else :
        LED="0"
    s1.sendall(LED.encode()) 
    DW.pop(0)
    DW.append(data1)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,DT,'b')
    ax2.plot(xar,DW,'cm')
                                                 # close connection
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
xar = list(range(200))
DT = list([0]*200)
DW = list([0]*200)
ani = []
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.tight_layout(pad=2)
plt.show
```

however i received this error in the terminal :

```
UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. 
This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation 
to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists 
until you have outputted the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
```

any thoughts how to solve it  ??

thanks

Comment: you forgot `()` in line `plt.show()`

Comment: is this full error message? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `FuncAnimation` sends integer value (frame number) to `animate` and it has to get it `def animate(number):`

Comment: are you sure you run this code? I get error with `animate` because it doesn't get `number` and I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you run different code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it doesn't gives me your error message.

Maybe you run code from different file.

---

To make sure I put my code which has few small modifications to make it more readable.

**client.py**

```
import socket
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT1 = 1234   
PORT2 = 5678

BUF_SIZE = 1024

message1 = "Temp"
message2 = "Wind"

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.connect((HOST, PORT1)) 
s1.sendall(message1.encode())

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.connect((HOST, PORT2)) 
s2.sendall(message2.encode())

def animate(number):
    
    # --- temp ---
    
    #s1.sendall(messageq.encode())
    data = s1.recv(BUF_SIZE).decode()
    data = int(data)
    
    print('received temp:', data)
    
    if data > 30:
        LED = "1023"
    else:
        LED = "0"
        
    s1.sendall(LED.encode())
    
    #time.sleep(2)
    
    data_temp.pop(0)
    data_temp.append(data)

    # --- water ---
    
    #s2.sendall(messagew.encode())
    data = s2.recv(BUF_SIZE).decode()
    data = int(data)
    
    print('received water level:', data) 
    if data > 5:
        LED = "1023"
    else:
        LED = "0"
        
    s2.sendall(LED.encode())
    
    #time.sleep(2)
    
    data_water.pop(0)
    data_water.append(data)

    # --- update ---
    
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    
    ax1.plot(xar, data_temp, 'b')
    ax2.plot(xar, data_water, 'c')

# ----

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

xar = list(range(200))

data_temp  = [0]*200
data_water = [0]*200

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)

plt.tight_layout(pad=2)
plt.show()
```

**server1.py**

```
import socket
import time
import random

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1234   
BUF_SIZE = 1024

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(2)
    while True:
        sock, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr, sock)

        while True:
            data = sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
            value = random.randint(0, 100)
            sock.sendall(str(value).encode())
            time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    s.close()
```

**server2.py**

Only `PORT` is different.

```
import socket
import time
import random

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5678
BUF_SIZE = 1024

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(2)
    while True:
        sock, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr, sock)

        while True:
            data = sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
            value = random.randint(0, 100)
            sock.sendall(str(value).encode())
            time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    s.close()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much  furas , you made my day